# How do i pass information to a Uilabel in the second view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to swift and i'm just trying to learn the different techniques.

The Situation:
I have 2 view controllers. View controller number 1 consist of four buttons (north, south, east, west) for example. Lets say you click on the north button. It should take you to View controller number 2 and the UiLabel in View controller 2 should be displaying the name of whatever button that was pressed ("North" in this case).
I know that when you're passing information forward, you should use the "prepare for segue" method but is there a way to do this with all 4 buttons? I also have a optional string variable in View Controller 2 that should catch the information being passed from View controller 1. I've searched everywhere but i haven't gotten an answer on this.

The code i have currently in view controller 1:

```
@IBAction func north(sender: UIButton) {

}
@IBAction func east(sender: UIButton) {

}
@IBAction func west(sender: UIButton) {

}
@IBAction func south(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

The Code i have currently in View Controller 2:

```
@IBoutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

var updateTheLabel: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
label2.text = updateTheLabel!
}
```

Question: 
how do i perform a segue with all four buttons to go to the Second view controller and update the UiLabel respectively?

Comment: You want to pass UI Element between ViewControllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @ahmad-farrag's solution

You can modify your IB Actions to pick up the text from the button that is pressed

```
var buttonText = ""

@IBAction func north(sender: UIButton) {
   buttonText = sender.currentTitle.text
}
@IBAction func east(sender: UIButton) {
   buttonText = sender.currentTitle.text
}
@IBAction func west(sender: UIButton) {
   buttonText = sender.currentTitle.text
}
@IBAction func south(sender: UIButton) {
   buttonText = sender.currentTitle.text
}
```

This will assign the text from the buttons to the `buttonText` variable. Now in your `prepareForSegue` let us assume the two view controllers are connected by a segue with an identifier `secondControllerSegue`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "secondControllerSegue" {
      let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
      controller.updateTheLabel = buttonText
   }
}
```

This will send the `buttonText` we have captured earlier to the `secondViewController`

Comment: Thank you!, This helped me to make more sense of the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Just remove the segues from your storyboard, Then do it programmatically and make your updateTheLabel property public.

for example:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewControllerIdentifier") as? SecondViewController
secondViewController.updateTheLabel = "Whatever you like"

//Then push or present to the secondViewController depending on your hierarchy.
//self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController!, animated: true)
//or
//self.presentViewController(secondViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using NSNotificition Centre
in ViewController

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.testObserver(_:)), name: "testObserver", object: ios)
```

Destination View Controller

```
 func testObserver(noti : NSNotification){
    title = noti.object as? String
}
```

Comment: Notifications between directly related controllers is bad programming habit.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for Guidance.May i know Proper reason?

Comment: Because using a segue you get the object reference to the destination controller for free. Notifications are only useful if being sent to multiple objects or to an object which is not related to the sender at all.